# c++ hooking vtables and their virtual functions

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

Recently i've been learning about vmt hooking, however there is this one annoying bug that I cannot seem to fix and i'm not sure what exactly is the problem

my vmt hook doesn't override specific function pointers, what i'm trying to do is find the vmt > make a copy of it > switch the vmt pointers so my custom vmt gets called.

I made a simple application with 2 classes and virtual functions,
[how it looks in ida](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwmgP.png)

to calculate the address of vmt I am doing base address of our process + virtual address of vmt

```
auto base = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>((GetModuleHandleA(nullptr)));
std::uintptr_t* vTable = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t*>(base + 0x4268);
```

afterwards I cast the address to a class that is rebuilt from the class i'm trying to hook

```
hk_class1 = reinterpret_cast<hook_this_class_t*>(&vTable);
```

now it seems that it does find the class correctly, however at the same time its not ( hear me out )
for testing purposes in my application where i'm trying to hook I added code that shows me the dynamic address of vtable

```
 std::uintptr_t* vtable = *reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t**>(&object);
    std::uintptr_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t*>((DWORD)vtable - (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA(nullptr));
```

printing out (VOID*)ptr will give us the dynamic address of our object that is hook_this_class

back in my dll I have two seperate classes

```
hk_class = reinterpret_cast<hook_this_class_t*>(0x08C4138);
hk_class1 = reinterpret_cast<hook_this_class_t*>(&vTable);
```

hk_class uses the dynamic address for testing purposes
and hk_class1 uses a calculated one

if we take a look at the comparison we can see both yield different results

my hook works if I use the dynamic address, but if I use the &vTable address then I get wrong results, index counter goes to random numbers and it never hooks anything!
[comparison between hk_class and hk_class1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQCww.png)

as you can see the most notable difference is that our virtual functions mismatch, in hk_class1 at the index 0 there is some RTTI complete object locator while there should be my virtual function add(int, int)

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong? if you need more info to be posted make sure to ask and I will provide it.

Update:

after enabling rtti I am still unable to perform a vmt hook, however I think i am getting closer and closer to it. now when I use the base + va formula it actually lands me into the class and it resembles one ( however it still gives me a few issues)

[watch list, class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9ch1.png)

The first noticable thing is that my dll is unable to read string and a is broken value

is it possible that my hooking functions are broken ?

```
VMTHook::VMTHook(void* objectPtr){
if (objectPtr == nullptr)
    return;

this->ptr_ptr_base_class = static_cast<std::uintptr_t**>(objectPtr);

while (static_cast<std::uintptr_t*>(*this->ptr_ptr_base_class)[this->index_count])
    ++this->index_count;

const std::size_t table_size = index_count * sizeof(std::uintptr_t);

this->ptr_original_Vmt = *this->ptr_ptr_base_class;
this->ptr_New_Vmt = std::make_unique<std::uintptr_t[]>(this->index_count);

std::memcpy(this->ptr_New_Vmt.get(), this->ptr_original_Vmt, table_size);

*this->ptr_ptr_base_class = this->ptr_New_Vmt.get();
}
```

and to redirect the functions

```
this->ptr_New_Vmt[index] = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(our_function);
```

with index and our_function being passed in as a parameter ofc

Comment: compiled with/without RTTI option(s)?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux RTTI is on by default in MSVC compiler right ? if so then its on, i never disabled it

Comment: I think it is the other way around - RTTI is not default option

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gr-enable-run-time-type-information?view=msvc-160

By default, /GR is on. or am I reading the sentence wrong somehow lol

Comment: Mmmm... Just made empty console project in VS 2019. RTTI field is empty in the project properties

Comment: And thre is no /GR switch in commmand-line

Comment: I updated my thread, even with RTTI enabled I still run into some weird issue.